# How to filter a Lua array inplace?

Tags: lua

How to filter a Lua array inplace?

For example, having an array of  `{ 1, 5, 7 }` and a function `function(elem) return elem > 1 end`, the inplace filtering function should change the array to `{ 5, 7 }`. It is also desired not to break `ipairs` iteration on the array, so the array should still start with index `1`.

By "array" I mean the part of a Lua table that starts with key `1` and goes through consecutive integer keys until it finds a `nil`. The same thing you iterate with `ipairs`.

Comment: Your "Lua array" construct is a bit too strict. `ipairs` and `#` operate on a Lua table "with a sequence" as you've described. But, non-positive and non-integer keys do not affect them so could be permitted in such a table.

Comment: @TomBlodget You may be right. I just gave the simplest definition I could. If there is a solution for any other "array" definitions that keep `ipairs` working, it's interesting as well. You know what, I better remove the array word from my question and focus just on `ipairs`. Thanks.

Comment: @Piglet I can't judge myself if I'm wrong or not opening a topic. Since I raised it, I think it's okay...

Answer (score 1):

The following function solves the problem:

```
function filter_inplace(arr, func)
    local new_index = 1
    local size_orig = #arr
    for old_index, v in ipairs(arr) do
        if func(v, old_index) then
            arr[new_index] = v
            new_index = new_index + 1
        end
    end
    for i = new_index, size_orig do arr[i] = nil end
end
```

Comment: what does func refer to?

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка it should be a function that tells whether an element of the array should be kept or not. E.g. something like `function(elem) return elem > 1 end` from the question of this QA

Comment: ah, thank you, that was my suspicion based on the content of your question

Comment: This is the asymptotically optimal solution. It (1) has linear time complexity and (2) only needs constant auxiliary space.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're changing the indexes while iterating, I'd use a while loop.

```
function filterInplace(t, func)
    local i = 1
    while (i <= #t) do
        if func(t[i]) then
            -- value passes test
            i = i + 1
        else
            table.remove(t, i)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: This has quadratic time complexity in the worst case as each call to `table.remove` has linear time complexity.